# AWK: print only lines with wildcard

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following `file.txt`:

```
string1 <TAB> A21332
string2 <TAB> A45221
string3 <TAB> 
string4 <TAB> A92092
```

and I want to use awk to print for lines where the column 2 begins with an 'A'

this is my code

`awk -F$'\t' '$2 ~ "A" {print $0}' file.txt`

but it does not work...

Comment: Doesn't work, means you get no output, too much output or an error message?  Seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: @grail: That may not be the right approach, it will even match `string4 92009A` which should not be the case.

Comment: @Inian: currently the OP has not said that it can't be like that :)

Comment: @grail: `column 2 begins with an 'A'` ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Awk` as below, use the regex construct `^` to indicate the string-start

```
awk -v FS=$'\t' '$2 ~ "^A"' file
string1 A21332
string2 A45221
string4 A92092
```

removing the `bash` specific `$'\t'` syntax, you can use it as

```
awk -vFS="\t" '$2 ~ "^A"' file
```

and removing the `GNU Awk` specific `-vFS=` syntax & initialising de-limiter as part of `BEGIN` clause

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}$2 ~ "^A"' file
```

and removing the dynamic regex and just using `//` de-limiter as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}$2 ~ /^A/' file
```

Comment: If the data is to be believed, there is a space between the tab and the 'A', so your example would not work.

Comment: @grail: I think it is quite clear, OP meant the field separator between two columns to be `<tab>` and no spaces to be considered.

Comment: @EdMorton: Fixed now! Thanks as usual!

Comment: You're welcome. You could use `-F'\t'` instead of `BEGIN{FS="\t"}` if you like. Just sayin'...

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is without tab

Comment: without SPACE (today is obviously not my day)